# Accessing remote WCF function is not possible

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

Im trying to access a remote wcf function in a service from the test application (Client), while executing it says service expired. 
I tried
1) disabling firewall,
2) checked with SSl certificates, but didn't helped me 
Could anyone help me why im unable to call this wcf function running on remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

First steps: enable logging.
See 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging

And:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/recommended-settings-for-tracing-and-message-logging

To look at the logs, use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/viewing-message-logs

If the logs do not make sense, post back here.

Comment: Hi,
After retreiving the log traces i see the response like below

<s:Header></s:Header>
<s:Body>
<ProcessReleaseResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<ProcessReleaseResult>REQUEST EXPIRED</ProcessReleaseResult>

It looks like request is getting expired, this is happening in my system only. when i execute in another machine i can see the reply as SUCCESS.
Any thoughts on the issue.

Comment: You're going to need to debug with the service owner. That response is from their service, not wcf